# Where is a good place to put socket.io logic in sails.js

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js

where is a good place to put my logic if I want to use `sails.io`? Is `config/bootstrap.js` a good place to put it? Or is there some other file I can create somewhere else?

This code below works:

```
// config/bootstrap.js
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

  sails.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Got a connected client");

  });

  cb();
};
```

Comment: you might find this answer helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/19939700/1262998.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't support this until `0.9.4`.

step 1. Get the latest version of sails.js

step 2. Generate sails with the the cli

step 3. See `config/sockets.js`, customize `onConnect` function, see below:

```
module.exports.sockets = {

  // This custom onConnect function will be run each time AFTER a new socket connects
  // (To control whether a socket is allowed to connect, check out `authorization` config.)
  // Keep in mind that Sails' RESTful simulation for sockets 
  // mixes in socket.io events for your routes and blueprints automatically.
  onConnect: function(session, socket) {

    // By default: do nothing
    // This is a good place to subscribe a new socket to a room, inform other users that
    // someone new has come online, or any other custom socket.io logic
    console.log("Got a connected client");

  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For logic processing, you can put it in the following places:

1. Controller: if a request should trigger a real-time event
2. Service: if you want :) but I think Controller is referred
3. /config/socket.js onConnect(), onDisconnect(): If you want to add or remove the connected socket to/from some rooms, or some initial socket setup, etc.
4. /policies/sessionAuth.js: for some real-time authen logic
5. Other places...

Beside, you should consider the [resourceful-pubsub](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub) feature which may help you save a lot of effort on implementing real-time process with socket. I found that it's very cool :)