# How do I subscribe to a model instance in Sails.JS?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js

I am attempting to use the subscribe function [described here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/wiki/sockets#modelsubscribereq-models). However, when editing `/assets/js/app.js`, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Room is not defined
```

So, I am not entirely sure why, but it cannot find my model. Here is my code:

```
Room.subscribe(req, [{id: "5278861ab9a0d2cd0e000001"}], function (response) {
  console.log('subscribed?');
  console.log(response);
});
```

and here is is in the context of app.js

```
(function (io) {

  // as soon as this file is loaded, connect automatically, 
  var socket = io.connect();
  if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
    log('Connecting to Sails.js...');
  }

  socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {

    // Listen for Comet messages from Sails
    socket.on('message', function messageReceived(message) {

      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // Replace the following with your own custom logic
      // to run when a new message arrives from the Sails.js
      // server.
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      log('New comet message received :: ', message);
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    });


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Here's where you'll want to add any custom logic for
    // when the browser establishes its socket connection to 
    // the Sails.js server.
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    log(
        'Socket is now connected and globally accessible as `socket`.\n' + 
        'e.g. to send a GET request to Sails, try \n' + 
        '`socket.get("/", function (response) ' +
        '{ console.log(response); })`'
    );
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // This is the part I added: 
    Room.subscribe(req, [{id: "5278861ab9a0d2cd0e000001"}], function (response) {
      console.log('subscribed?');
      console.log(response);
    });
    //


   });


  // Expose connected `socket` instance globally so that it's easy
  // to experiment with from the browser console while prototyping.
  window.socket = socket;


  // Simple log function to keep the example simple
  function log () {
    if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
      console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    }
  }


})(
```

Am I going about this the right way? should I be storing this *directly in* app.js?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To subscribe to a model instance, I use the following **Real-Time Model Event** pattern, some of which resides on the client and some on the server.  Keep in mind the client can’t just subscribe itself- you have to send a request to the server letting it know that you’d *like* to be subscribed-- this is the only way to do it securely. (e.g. you might want to publish notifications with sensitive information-- you want to make sure a connected socket has permission to see that information before subscribing them to it.)

I’m going to use an example of an app with a User model.  Let’s say I  want to notify folks when existing users login.

### Client-Side (Part I)

On the client-side, for simplicity, I’m going to use the existing `app.js` file in the `/assets/js` folder (or `/assets/linker/js` folder if you used the `--linker` switch when you built the app.)

To send my socket request to the server within `assets/js/app.js`, I’m going to use the `socket.get()` method.  This method mimics the functionality of an AJAX “get” request (i.e. `$.get()` ) but uses sockets instead of HTTP.  (FYI: You also have access to `socket.post()`, `socket.put()`, and `socket.delete()`).

The code would look something like this:

```
 
// Client-side (assets/js/app.js)
// This will run the `welcome()` action in `UserController.js` on the server-side.

//...

socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {

  console.log("This is from the connect: ", this.socket.sessionid);

  socket.get(‘/user/welcome’, function gotResponse () {
    // we don’t really care about the response
  });

//...
```

### Server-Side (Part I)

Over in the `welcome()` action in `UserController.js`, **now** we can actually subscribe this client (socket) to notifications using the `User.subcribe()` method.

```
 
// api/UserController.js

//...
  welcome: function (req, res) {
    // Get all of the users
    User.find().exec(function (err, users) {
      // Subscribe the requesting socket (e.g. req.socket) to all users (e.g. users)
      User.subscribe(req.socket, users);
    });
  }

//...
```

### Back on the client-side (Part II)...

I want the socket to ‘listen’ for messages I’m going to send it from the server.  To do this I’ll use:

```
 
// Client-side (assets/js/app.js)
// This will run the `welcome()` action in `UserController.js` on the backend.

//...

socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {

  console.log("This is from the connect: ", this.socket.sessionid);

  socket.on('message', function notificationReceivedFromServer ( message ) {
    // e.g. message ===
    // {
    //   data: { name: ‘Roger Rabbit’},
    //   id: 13,
    //   verb: ‘update’
    // }
  });

  socket.get(‘/user/welcome’, function gotResponse () {
    // we don’t really care about the response
  });

// ...
```

### Back on the server-side (Part II)...

Finally, I’ll start sending out messages, server-side, by using: `User.publishUpdate(id);`

```
 
// api/SessionController.js

//...
  // User session is created
  create: function(req, res, next) {

    User.findOneByEmail(req.param('email'), function foundUser(err, user) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      // Authenticate the user using the existing encrypted password...
      // If authenticated log the user in...

      // Inform subscribed sockets that this user logged in
      User.publishUpdate(user.id, {
        loggedIn: true,
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        action: ' has logged in.'
      });
    });
  }
//...
```

You can also check out [Building a Sails Application: Ep21 - Integrating socket.io and sails with custom controller actions using Real Time Model Events](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/10/10/building-a-sails-application-ep21-integrating-socket-dot-io-and-sails-with-custom-controller-actions-using-real-time-model-events/) for more information.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test all of this yet - but just reading this has helped tremendously. Also, thanks for the SailsCast!

Comment: Yes, thanks for this.  The sails documentation needs to be improved to better explain this particular flow.

Comment: note that the sails API has changed in 0.10 and `Back on the client-side (Part II)...` works different now: listen to the modelName instead of `message`.

Comment: Since this is a popular question on google, I thought I would mention that in sails v0.12, if you are wanting to watch the entire model, .subscribe with a second paramter will lock down your subscription to all records that already exist at the time you are connecting. If you want the client to be notified of new records, you would do `User.watch(req);`, which will notify the client of all new records, and automatically subscribe them to them. Also, you would use `User.subscribe(req.socket, users);` to subscribe the client to all changes made to the already existing records.